# My download button has moved too far to the right for me to download podcasts directly to my phone

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, podcasts

I used to download new podcast episodes by going to the podcast on my phone and pushing the "get more episodes" button. I have done this for years now and had no problems.

Suddenly on June 14th the download button has moved too far to the right so that I can't access it to push it and download the podcast. It doesn't work to flip the phone and I can't pull the screen over to access the button.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot please?

Answer (score 1):

Super frustrating—same thing happened to me. I found that if I went to read the ratings (an option at the top of the screen) and then back, they had moved back to regular position. See if this works for you.